# Using MailKit IMAP to read and save attachment to file share. Getting stream.Read, stream.Write timeout errors

Tags: c#, file-io, stream, email-attachments, mailkit

I actually had this working for `.pdf` files and could not get it to work for `.xls`.

Now I cannot seem to get ether to work. Note I have looked at all other post from jsteadfast and this is the code I came up with.

When I read the Message I have nothing in Attachments there are 2 files the body of the text in a `.txt` file and the attachment which is in the `.pdf` or `.xls` file both are in `message.BodyParts`.

I just want to save the attachments to a file share. This is a .NET worker service. Azure Active Directory. Mailbox is outlook.office365.com.

In my stream I get

> "WriteTimeout = {stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException}"

```
using (var imapclient = new ImapClient())
{
    imapclient.Connect(mailbox, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect, stoppingToken);
    imapclient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
    imapclient.Authenticate(new SaslMechanismOAuth2(userName, authenticationResult.AccessToken), stoppingToken);
    imapclient.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    var messages = imapclient.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);
    int unnamed = 0;

    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        var multipart = message.Body as BodyPartMultipart;
        var basic = message.Body as BodyPartBasic;
        var bodyParts = message.BodyParts.ToList(); //Foreach message.BodyParts bodyParts[0] contains .txt, bodyParts[1] contains .pdf
        var archive = imapclient.GetFolder(_archive);

        if (multipart != null)
        {
            foreach (var attachment in bodyParts)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment.FileName)) //when it's .pdf it has a FileName 
                {
                    var mime = (MimePart)imapclient.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, attachment);
                    var fileName = mime.FileName;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                        fileName = string.Format("unnamed-{0}", ++unnamed);

                    using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
                    {
                        string[] splitFileName = fileName.Split(".");

                        fileName = splitFileName[0] + string.Format("_{0:MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-fff}", DateTime.Now) + "." + splitFileName[1];

                        //SaveStreamToDirectory(stream, fileName, armadaTargetDir);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(armadaTargetDir, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        }
                    }

                    //imapclient.Inbox.MoveTo(message.UniqueId, archive);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (basic != null && basic.IsAttachment)
        {
            var mime = (MimePart)imapclient.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, basic);
            var fileName = mime.FileName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                fileName = string.Format("unnamed-{0}", ++unnamed);

            using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
                mime.ContentObject.DecodeTo(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried the following code example that should work as well according to jsteadfast. As you can see here I am trying to set the stream.Position. Just to be clear the file is being saved to the file share. but with no data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                        using (var imapclient = new ImapClient())
                    {
                        imapclient.Connect(mailbox, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect, stoppingToken);
                        imapclient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                        imapclient.Authenticate(new SaslMechanismOAuth2(userName, authenticationResult.AccessToken), stoppingToken);
                        imapclient.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

                        var messages = imapclient.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);
                        int unnamed = 0;

                        IList<UniqueId> uids = imapclient.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.All);

                        foreach (UniqueId uid in uids)
                        {
                            MimeMessage message = imapclient.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);

                            foreach (MimeEntity attachment in message.Attachments)
                            {
                                var fileName = attachment.ContentDisposition?.FileName ?? attachment.ContentType.Name;

                                using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
                                {
                                    stream.Flush();
                                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                                    if (attachment is MessagePart)
                                    {
                                        var rfc822 = (MessagePart)attachment;

                                        rfc822.Message.WriteTo(stream);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var part = (MimePart)attachment;

                                        part.Content.DecodeTo(stream);

                                    }

                                    SaveStreamToDirectory(stream, fileName, armadaTargetDir);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
{
    string[] splitFileName = fileName.Split(".");

    fileName = splitFileName[0] + string.Format("_{0:MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-fff}", DateTime.Now) + "." + splitFileName[1];

    //SaveStreamToDirectory(stream, fileName, armadaTargetDir);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(armadaTargetDir, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

You are creating a file stream called `stream` (which will be empty). Then you create a second file stream called `fileStream`.

Next, you are copying the contents of `stream` into `fileStream` but `stream` is empty because you just created it and so it would be empty.

In your second code sample, what does the method `SaveStreamToDirectory(stream, fileName, armadaTargetDir);` look like? My guess is that you need to rewind `stream` (aka seek back to position 0) in order to read from the stream.

Note: In your second example, after creating `stream`, you immediately call `stream.Flush();` and then `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`. Neither of these calls make any sense to do right after creating the stream. When you call `Flush()`, you are telling the stream to write all of its buffered data to the file (but you haven't written anything, so why would you call Flush()?). Then you are seeking back to the beginning of the file, but since you haven't read or written anything, you are *already* at the beginning of the file, so it is pointless.